# What is `function floor() { [native code] }` in console

Tags: javascript

How can I see how native js functions are implemented in a browser?

I've tried `Math.floor.toString()` but it returns `"function floor() { [native code] }"` and I can't step into the function using debugger.

Comment: I don't think the native source code itself is present in the compiled executable. Do you?

Comment: because the function internally benefits from native code implemented on the browser level

Comment: Native = compiled code of the browser not a javascrit function so you can't.

Comment: You cannot access the code unless it is available through github for example for the given browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this from the console, because the functions are part of the *compiled* browser executable … or, rather, its JavaScript engine. It *is* native code.

You may be able to read the source code for that engine, though, depending on which browser you're using. For example, [Chrome's v8 source is on GitHub](https://github.com/v8/v8).

Comment: This answer is correct and such it should be marked accordingly.

Comment: Already upvoted and just said that this answer should be marked as the correct one by the OP as it is very correct one for the given question.

Answer (score -3):

**Updated**

It's a native function. I'm guessing you could download the source code for a browser, as that's where it's implemented

[Firefox Source code for example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It doesn't, my bad :D